# Get PHP JSON Data per AFNetwork

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

The following:

```
// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

gives me: `[{"id":"1","app_id":"com.razeware.test"}]` - tested with a web browser.

But with AFNetworking I get the data but not in a easy `JSONArray` format.

[image]

**Edit

The following code is how I want to get the data:

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:@"http://lochalhost/con.php" parameters:nil progress:nil
     //if successfull -> data to array
         success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
     {
         NSArray *Temp=responseObject;**
```

So I tried to put it in an NSArray. This is what I normally would expect:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by *not in a easy JSON Array format.*

Comment: what tool did you use to product that picture ? **code is better than pictures, btw** , we cant edit your pic to quote this, or even attempt to answer. I see the trailing end of what seems to be 'easy JSON'.  Also btw, JSON is not an array,

Comment: `AFJSONResponseSerializer` doesn't seems to bet set. Could you print `responseObject`?

Comment: Printing description of responseObject->_length:
(unsigned short) _length = 42

Comment: `manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];` => `manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];`, if not, `responseObject` is a `NSData` object, and `temp` would have to be initialized like this: `NSArray *temps = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:0 error:nil];`